Basic: Newton's Laws of Motion doubt regarding resolution of forces
This is a basic question I had while solving a problem. It's related to the resolution of forces along an incline.
The problem involved an inclined plane (angle of inclination theta). There's a weighing machine kept on the plane with a guy standing on it. A pretty straightforward problem asking us to calculate the mass as recorded by the weighing machine.
$Mg\cos\theta = N$ (taking the component of $mg$ perpendicular to the incline)
$N/g = M\cos\theta$
Initially while solving this I made a mistake. I took the component of $N$ perpendicular to the ground (i.e., in the direction of $Mg$).
$N\cos\theta = Mg$
$N = Mg/\cos\theta$
$N/g = M/\cos\theta$
Over here the normal exceeds the weight ($Mg$). Is that why this is incorrect? I thought both of these methods would give the same result. What must I keep in mind while resolving forces so that I can avoid such errors? Also, my apologies if this is a silly doubt. It's my first time learning this and it's taking me some time.

$Mg$ is the main, full, weight. You are trying to break this up into parts, which must be smaller than the full thing. The other case is not valid.

Think about what happens if the angle is 90$^0$. The man would be in free fall and weightless.

Hmm, makes sense. But I'm still not able to understand.

Could you expand on the setup of the question you've posted? Is the diagram in the vertical plane (such that the weight of the balls act downwards)? Do the balls have the same mass? Are the black lines labelled T1, T2 massless strings?
If the answers to all of the above are yes then the system isn't physically possible, at least not in equilibrium. Ball B will always have an unbalanced force accelerating it to the left.

The reason why the second method fails is that physically this is the assertion that an object on the slope cannot roll downwards, rather than the assertion that the object cannot sink into the slope (which is what we want). To see why this is the case, consider instead the simpler case of just a ball on the slope, no weighing machines.
$Mg cos(\theta) = N$ is the assertion that the perpendicular (relative to the surface of the slope) components of force must cancel. So F=ma resolved in this direction would give us zero acceleration into the plane. In other words, the object cannot accelerate into the slope, which of course makes sense physically as this prevents the object from sinking through the surface.
If alternatively you had said $N cos(\theta) = Mg$, you are asserting that no acceleration can occur vertically. So the object on the slope cannot roll downwards at all, which of course physically we know isn't true.

Think of ice and a sidewalk. Both will hold you up, keeping you from sinking into them. That is, both exert a reaction for on you just as hard as you push into them. This force does not lift you off the surface, because if you stop pushing, so do they. This reaction force is always perpendicular to the surface.
A sidewalk also exerts a force that resists sliding parallel to the sidewalk. This is friction. It is parallel to the surface.
Ice is (pretty close to) frictionless. If you push a mass diagonally downward into the ice, the ice keeps it from sinking in. But it does not keep the mass from accelerating sideways along the surface.
If you have an inclined plane made of ice or concrete, these same considerations apply. The reaction force is perpendicular to the inclined surface. Friction is along it.
If you have a mass on an icy slope, gravity pulls straight down. You can break find two forces that add up to the gravitational force, where one is parallel to the slope and the other perpendicular to it. The slope will generate a reaction force to the perpendicular force and nothing for the parallel force. So it is important to know how big is the component of the gravitational force perpendicular to the surface.
You can apply the same thing to the string. If you pull on the string, the string pulls back on you just hard enough to keep the string from stretching. It does nothing to keep the string from rotating around the pivot. Weight is a force that is vertical. Part of it tries to stretch the string and part tries to rotate it.
